# Discord JS Bot - Gamedig query info to string and number type

Tags: javascript, discord.js, gamedig

code returns me in query, I want specific two of values one: `clients` in `number` type and second in `string` type: players`. There is my code:

```js
    Gamedig.query({
        type: 'fivem',
        host: '178.33.45.164'
    }).then((GD) => {
        console.log(GD);

        console.log(usp.toString)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("server is offline");
    })
```

Comment: Can you edit in the output of `GD`?

Comment: well GD is only name of query, i cant edit it, it is showing in my terminal and i want it to show in message. But not all of query stuff, only players: [] and clients: .  I am asking if anyone has method to get things from query

Comment: I understand, but I need to see the output of `console.log(GD);` to help you here since I don't know the structure of the output

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zxDzWHhb - here is code that shows in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Note: For `players` I see there are 2 keys called `players`.

```js
Gamedig.query({
        type: 'fivem',
        host: '178.33.45.164'
    }).then((GD) => {
        console.log(GD.raw.clients); // Gets clients
        console.log(GD.raw.players); // Gets players (raw is the game specific data that the game server provides so there might be more data in this one)
        console.log(GD.players); // Gets players (not the one inside `raw`)

        console.log(usp.toString)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("server is offline");
    })
```

Comment: and how can i get value of label name from the GD.raw.players

Comment: What's the output of GD.raw.players rn?